# Cron issue with Drush 8

Tags: drush, cron

My Drupal 6 sites are hosted on a Linux server with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6 installed. I use Drush 8 which I installed via composer. 
I set a cron job via cPanel which runs every day this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to execute all the cron jobs with drush
echo '**************** French site *******************'
cd /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/fr.mysite.com
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/bin/drush -v core-cron
echo '**************** English site ******************'
cd /home/myuser/public_html/en/sites/en.mysite.com
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/bin/drush -v core-cron
echo '**************** Spanish site ******************'
cd /home/myuser/public_html/es/sites/es.mysite.com
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/bin/drush -v core-cron
echo '**************** Completed **********************'
```

But it fails and ends with:

```
**************** French site *******************
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_open(): Descriptor item must be either an array or a File-Handle in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>434</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_get_status() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>435</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>436</b><br />
**************** English site ******************
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_open(): Descriptor item must be either an array or a File-Handle in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>434</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_get_status() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>435</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>436</b><br />
**************** Spanish site ******************
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_open(): Descriptor item must be either an array or a File-Handle in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>434</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_get_status() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>435</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>436</b><br />
**************** Completed **********************
```

The strange thing is that when I manually run `drush -v core-cron` on any site, the cron run ends successfully. I really don't know where the problem comes from.

Comment: Looks like your cron script is using php-cgi instead of php-cli. Compare the environment variables, php and php.ini being used, etc. between the working and non-working users (cron user, vs. user you are using when manually running Drush).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this cron script worked well with Drush 6 before. Would it have been able to work yet if there was a php-cgi / php-cli problem?

Comment: Probably not, but Drush 7 and earlier are unsupported; been a long time since I've used Drush 6.

Comment: What about adding "php -v" as the first line of your script (after the shebang line of course), and then run the script through cron and manually - to verify which version of PHP is executed in each situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments to the question, I've added `php -v` as the first line of my script after the shebang line and run it both manually and through cron.

Manually, I've run `sh myscript.sh` and got:

```
PHP 5.5.33 (cli)
```

and the script's ended successfully.

Through cron, I've got:

```
PHP 5.5.33 (cgi-fcgi)
```

and the script's ended in failure.

So it's indeed a php-cgi / php-cli problem: cron is using php-cgi instead of php-cli in my case.

But since I'm hosted on a managed VPS and since I don't intend to use D6 for much longer, I've finally found easier to write another script using wget:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to execute all the cron jobs with wget
echo '**************** French site *******************'
wget --no-cache --spider http://fr.mysite.com/cron.php
echo '**************** English site ******************'
wget --no-cache --spider http://en.mysite.com/cron.php
echo '**************** Spanish site ******************'
wget --no-cache --spider http://es.mysite.com/cron.php
echo '**************** Completed **********************'
```

It's a little slower than using drush but it runs well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that instead of calling `cd` within your script, you either set up drush aliases or pass the `--root` and `--uri` parameters to the cron request.

```
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/bin/drush -v --root=/home/myuser/public_html --uri=fr.mysite.com core-cron
```

That should make sure that drush is running in the right context.

You can also make sure that drush is running with the php that you would like by setting the `DRUSH_PHP` environment variable.